# Functionalities : Screen Sharing flutter webrtc

Tags: flutter, dart, screensharing, videocall, flutter-webrtc

**This is not a bug but I am not getting proper documentation for the screen-sharing using the web-RTC. So, can please anyone help me with this implementation?  If I get the documentation also it will be good enough for me.**

**Expected behavior:** When I make a call I am able to share my screen.  But right now not have any idea how to do that.

**Platform information**

- **Plugin version**:

  flutter_webrtc:
  git: https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/flutter-webrtc
- **OS**: Android, iOS
- **OS version**: All